# cardano preprod wallet balance is still zero after full node sync

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node

I'm following the instructions laid out in this article.

https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/cardano-wallet-js

I first ran cardano node and wallet using docker-compose on preprod network. I then created a new walletm, sent some test tokens using the faucet portal. The transaction was successful and verifiable on preprod cardano explorer. However the wallet balance when I call the api still shows as zero. I waited for the node to fully sync and change the status to "Ready" but even after that the wallet balance is still zero.

This is the network status(preview)

```
{
  network_info: { network_id: 'testnet', protocol_magic: 2 },
  network_tip: {
    absolute_slot_number: 7984597,
    epoch_number: 92,
    slot_number: 35797,
    time: '2023-01-25T09:56:37Z'
  },
  next_epoch: { epoch_number: 93, epoch_start_time: '2023-01-26T00:00:00Z' },
  node_era: 'babbage',
  node_tip: {
    absolute_slot_number: 7984492,
    epoch_number: 92,
    height: { quantity: 376281, unit: 'block' },
    slot_number: 35692,
    time: '2023-01-25T09:54:52Z'
  },
  sync_progress: { status: 'ready' },
  wallet_mode: 'node'
}
```

This is the code to check the balance.

```
const { Seed, WalletServer } = require("cardano-wallet-js");
(async function () {
let walletServer = WalletServer.init("http://127.0.0.1:8090/v2");
let wallets = await walletServer.wallets();
let id = wallets[0].id;
let wallet = await walletServer.getShelleyWallet(id);
let availableBalance = wallet.getAvailableBalance();
console.log(availableBalance);
})();
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information?

Comment: Sure.

Here is the transaction which I did from Faucet to my test preview wallet.
https://preview.cexplorer.io/address/addr_test1qzf90j270zkyfz7y8gtxmgjf02mee35xvzegfs8a93jgkvs89sjsfy7cyzh4me7et5qeldtq94nqn7ec7aejh4lptdaszd2560#data

These funds are not reflected when I run "wallet.getAvailableBalance()" in the code. Balance is still shown as 0.

Comment: I updated the question with the code to retrieve balance.

Comment: Can you console.log the address of the wallet?

Comment: When i run wallet.getNextAddress(), I get below response.
```
AddressWallet {
  id: 'addr_test1qzf90j270zkyfz7y8gtxmgjf02mee35xvzegfs8a93jgkvs89sjsfy7cyzh4me7et5qeldtq94nqn7ec7aejh4lptdaszd2560',
  state: 'unused'
}
```

Comment: Possibly you're running your local node on one network (preprod) and used the faucet and are checking on the other (preview). Try using the faucet to send assets to that address on the other network (https://docs.cardano.org/cardano-testnet/tools/faucet). And if they appear you have to decide which one you want to use. Here's the config files for each: https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments.html

Comment: Thank you. I double checked that I'm running the network on preview. I also tried Blockfrost (preview network) and queried those addresses, and I was able to find the balance here. So I suspect the cardano node that I'm running locally using docker is not updating for some reason. I'm running on Windows 11 btw.

Comment: Here's a similar issue (unfortunately unresolved, https://forum.cardano.org/t/cardano-wallet-js-debugging/104169/9)

But there might be some good suggestions to 1) check the logs and 2) check the docker configuration; might need to assign more RAM in the settings

Comment: I don't see any transaction for this wallet address on the blockchain explorer: https://preprod.cardanoscan.io/address/009257c95e78ac448bc43a166da2497ab79cc68660b284c0fd2c648b32072c250493d820af5de7d95d019fb5602d6609fb38f7732bd7e15b7b

Comment: Please look into the preview testnet, not preprod.